# Enable Windows 7 Soft Keyboard only for Logon Screen

Tags: windows-7, authentication, soft-keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I have developed my own Softkeyboard that I user for programs running on Windows 7 in a touch-only environment. However, for User-Logon I'd like to use the Microsoft Onscreen Keyboard.

Is it possible to automatically enable the Windows Onscreen Keyboard when a user selects a user-icon, and has to enter a password? What settings need to be done to do this?

When the user has successfully logged on, I don't want the Onscreen Keyboard to be displayed anymore in any Windows program, I need it only for logon.

Is that possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout this....

**1) Copy Onscreen Board Option which is available in accessibility.**

Start ->Programs -> Accessories -> Accessibility -> Right Click on On-Screen Board, Copy.

**2) Paste this in Startup**

Start -> Right click on Startup, Select Explore for all users, Paste it...

Alternatively you can come up with a .BAT file which will results in creating an **instance of On-Screen Keyboard**[Run command for on screen is **OSK**] then Using **Scheduled Tasks** which you can see in control panel options, make that batch file run when **when computer tasks**..

**Steps to create .bat file**
1. Open NotePad

2.Paste the below lines

@echo off

osk

1. *Save* that  As *[FileName].bat*.
2. To Test Double click on *[FileName].bat*, you should be able to see on screen keyboard on your screen.

**Detailed steps to use scheduled task**

1. Select Scheduled Tasks in control panel
2. Add Scheduled task
3. Click on Next
4. Browse for the batch file which you created(Test The batch file, when you double click on that file, should be able to see On Screen Keyboard on your screen)
5. Click on Next
6. Select "When my computer starts"
7. Click on Next
8. Provide the Credentials[*Better to provide administrative priviliges account credentials if you have Any Admin User Account in your machine*].
9. Click on Finish...

Regards,

Anoop

Comment: Hi,thanks, but this is not going to solve my problem, because I need to Onscreen Keyboard for user logon, not after the user has already logged on. Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: No, 
I assumed that you want the OSK on windows start up...

I will get back to you soon, working on it....

Sorry for the misguidance...



Regards,
Anoop